# Azure AD B2C passport-azure-ad: how validate issuer and obtain claims after logged in?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, azure-ad-b2c

This solution has been developed by using your example code (publish in GitHub) --> https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad/tree/master/examples/login-oidc-b2c

When I want to sign in with passport-azure-ad (Node JS Web App --> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-node/), Node JS output (on terminal) says:

`WARN: AzureAD: OIDC Passport Strategy/14580 on Llorenç-PC: We are not validating the issuer. This is fine if you are expecting multiple organizations to connect to your app. Otherwise you should validate the issuer`.

How can I fix it?

On the other hand, how can we get the user information/claims of users array?

```
var users = []; //Array of Users (app.js)
```